# My bluetooth connection unexpectedly closed in Android

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

```
java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
08-14 20:30:11.519 30608-1676/com.example.lg.scoreboardapp W/System.err: at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:434)
08-14 20:30:11.519 30608-1676/com.example.lg.scoreboardapp W/System.err: at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
08-14 20:30:11.519 30608-1676/com.example.lg.scoreboardapp W/System.err: at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)
08-14 20:30:11.519 30608-1676/com.example.lg.scoreboardapp W/System.err: at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
08-14 20:30:11.519 30608-1676/com.example.lg.scoreboardapp W/System.err: at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
08-14 20:30:11.519 30608-1676/com.example.lg.scoreboardapp W/System.err: at com.example.lg.scoreboardapp.MainActivity$ConnectThread.run(MainActivity.java:336)
```

Sometimes in my app, client unexpectedly closed. 
I don't know why......
I have three diveces.  one devices is server. others are client.
They are connected well, but one client was closed. other client is still open.
Please give me the solution...!!
It's MainActivitity.. 336Line`enter code here`

```
while(socket != null){
    i++;
    Log.d("MAinActivity","-----------------"+i+"-----------------------------");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    final String str1 = in.readLine(); //<<---Line 336
    Log.d("MainActivity","--------------------------------------"+str1+i);
    json1 = str1;
    parse();
}
```

It's ConnectThread  client

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "연결에 실패하였습니다.\n다시 시도하여 주세요", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
            //mkmsg("Client connection failed: "+e.getMessage().toString()+"\n");
        }
        socket = tmp;

    }

    public void run() {
        // mkmsg("Client running\n");
        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            socket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //mkmsg("Connect failed\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                socket.close();
                socket = null;
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                //mkmsg("unable to close() socket during connection failure: "+e2.getMessage().toString()+"\n");
                socket = null;
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        }
        // If a connection was accepted
        if (socket != null) {
            //mkmsg("Connection made\n");
            //mkmsg("Remote device address: "+socket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress().toString()+"\n");
            //Note this is copied from the TCPdemo code.
            try {
                int i=0;
                while(socket != null){
                    i++;
                    Log.d("MAinActivity","-----------------"+i+"-----------------------------");
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    final String str1 = in.readLine();
                    Log.d("MainActivity","--------------------------------------"+str1+i);
                    json1 = str1;
                    parse();
                }
                Log.d("MainActivity_341Line","socket is null.......... check this");
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MainActivity_341Line   socket is null.......... check this",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    }
                });


            } catch(Exception e) {
                //mkmsg("Error happened sending/receiving\n");
                e.printStackTrace();

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error happened sending/receiving\\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        Log.d("MainActivity_341Line","Error happened sending/receiving");
                    }
                });

                try {
                    socket.close();
                    socket = null;
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    //mkmsg("unable to close() socket during connection failure: "+e2.getMessage().toString()+"\n");
                    socket = null;
                    Log.d("MainActivity_341Line","Error happened "+e2);
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        } else {
            //mkmsg("Made connection, but socket is null\n");
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Made connection, but socket is null\\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            });
        }


    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            socket.close();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "채점기기와의 연결이 끝났습니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "채점기기와의 연결이 끝났습니다", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your run() method in your ConnectThread to this:

```
    public void run()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try
        {
            mmSocket.connect();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"Trying fallback...");
                mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket)
                        mmDevice.getClass()
                                .getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class}).invoke(mmDevice, 2);
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.e(TAG,"Connected");
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection!");
                try
                {
                    mmSocket.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e3)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + " socket during connection failure", e3);
                }
                connectionFailed();
                return;
            }
        }

        synchronized (BluetoothHelper.this)
        {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }
```